# Select 1 character after a certain character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that returns true if "@" is found.

```
emailValid = email.includes("@");
```

However, I need to select it only after 1 character of @.

`eg; test@g`

How do I do this?

I tried looking at JQuery's [contain selector](https://api.jquery.com/?s=contains), but I am unable to find a code where I can choose the character I want + 1 to it so that it will only select if it has that particular character and 1 character after it.

Can someone tell me if this is possible and how to go about doing it?

Comment: Are you trying to extract information from the string, or test something? Eg from `test@gmail.com`, are you trying to extract the character `g`, is that it? Or do you want to test if the character is `g`?

Comment: Nope, I am trying to just store the value if `@g` is present. But the thing is, I only know for certain that @ will be present, I won't know what the user will input after the @. So I need to know how to store a value if only @ +1 more character is present

Comment: What sort of character should appear after the `@`? Any character? Letters? Numbers? Punctuation? Whitespace?

Comment: g was just an example, it could be anything. It could be @ gmail, @ gma, @ yah, @ y.. So, I need to know how to store a value if @ + 1 or more character is present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.prototype.match` or `String.prototype.replace` to get the same.

```js
let str = 'something@abcd.com';
let word = str.match(/@(.)/)[1];
let word2 = str.replace(/.*@(.).*/, '$1')
let isValid = /@\w/.test(str) //rather \w can use [a-zA-Z] if only alphabets are valid or [a-zA-Z0-9] for including numbers too.
console.log(word)
console.log(word2)
console.log(isValid)
```

Comment: Do you know how I can return as true if there is a character present after the @ sign?

Comment: you want to check if there is one char present or can be one or more?

Comment: can be more , as long as there is a min of 1 character after the @

Comment: @Gosi added an `isValid` variable for the same.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I wanted, it returned true. Just that if its not true, it shows a console error.

Comment: The `+` in your `test()` is redundant. Also, `_` is invalid as the first character in a domain name

Comment: @Phil correct thanks. no need of `+`. wasn't sure which chars OP wants.

Comment: Yeah, I know. They didn't answer [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57686075/select-1-character-after-a-certain-character/57686181?noredirect=1#comment101817490_57686075)

Comment: just added in comment, whichever is required can be used.

Answer (score 2):

Given it looks like you're trying to validate an email address as having a [*domain* part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Domain) and domain names are typically restricted to beginning with a letter or number (though I could be wrong here), try

```js
emailValid = /@[a-z0-9]/i.test(email)
```

See [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

---

Keep in mind, comprehensive email address pattern validation is an absolute minefield. Your naive approach isn't too bad though.

Comment: typo, no closing brace `]`

Answer (score 1):

You need [String::match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) or [String::matchAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) methods.

For example,

```
var string1 = "test@g";
var string2 = "test-g";
var regexp = /(.*?)@(.*)/;

var result1 = string1.matchAll(regexp);
console.log(result1) // ["test@g", "test", "g"] 

var result2 = string2.matchAll(regexp);
console.log(result2) // null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  let str = "whatever@gmail.com";
  let k = str.indexOf("@");
  let plusOne = str.slice(k)
```

if there is no **@** symbol in the string, it **returns -1**

Comment: OP isn't looking for the character after `@`, they just want to validate that there is one present

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

```
/@[a-zA-Z0-9]/
```

- `@` - Match `@`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` - Match alphabet or digit

---

```js
let getstatus = (str) =>{
  return /@[a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(str)
}

console.log(getstatus('@'))
console.log(getstatus('@1'))
console.log(getstatus('1@'))
console.log(getstatus('@@'))
console.log(getstatus('@*'))
console.log(getstatus('@153753fddgv'))
console.log(getstatus('@bvbvbhd3753fddgv'))
```

**Note:-**  If you want to allow any other character you can add it to character class, if you want to allow anything except new line you can replace it with `.`